# Box asking about Intel Wifi connection to active management

Tags: lenovo-desktop-computer

I get a box that asks if I want to configure my wireless/wifi to connect with Intel active management it doesn't matter if I say yes, no or just close the box - it keeps coming back - is this legit and how can I stop it?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question off site>>>>https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-P-and-W-Series-Mobile-Workstations/Nonstop-popup-from-Intel-Active-Management-Technology-Profile-Synchronization/m-p/4389806

Comment: You can answer NO.   I have Intel and ProSet and it no longer asks me.